# Keep showing log message

Tags: 7

How can I disable this message?

[image: log excempt]

Comment: Do you want to fix the problem or just hide errors from your log? You can filter your log.

Comment: This is the only log i need to hide/fix. so it isnt usefull for me to disaple them all :).

Comment: It isn't useful to disable any error logging. The point of the errors is so you can see them and do something to address them, not hide them.

Comment: agree, just cant find the solution for the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the [Click Heatmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/click_heatmap) module enabled, either disable the module or add [clickheat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html) to the libraries folder.

Though, looking at the path that is output in the error, it seems that clickheat is probably being included in a template file somewhere, find the code and remove it. Do a search through your files to try to find 'click.php'.

Just disabling database logging will remove it, but will also not log anything else, so this is probably not your best option. Better to fix the problem rather than just hide it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to disable logging.

admin/config/development/logging

Disabling logging means you'll have no trace that your page is failing to load. Instead of pretending it's not happening, it would be better to find the underlying bug - why are users requesting a page that is failing to load?

If you need to disable the messages in the UI but would like to continue debugging, you can run this command from anywhere within your Drupal directory, assuming you have Drush installed:

```
drush watchdog-show --tail
```

This will give you all of the warnings / errors happening as you browse the site.

A truly robust Drupal installation will have an active log which is stored in a service like Splunk. Developers will intentionally add watchdog() functions in their code as a method of defense. Warnings and errors are critical for debugging problems with Drupal sites.